# com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.exceptions.InvalidAccessTokenException in onCreateView

Tags: android, mapbox

I have very similar code to the below that works in `AppCompatActivity.onCreate()`. I'm trying to do similarly in a Fragment instead of an Activity. In `Fragment.onCreateView()` however I get the InvalidAccessTokenException on the line indicated below. The access token is generated from [the Mapbox website](https://www.mapbox.com/studio/account/tokens/) and the String MAPBOX_TOKEN is assigned its value. What am I doing wrong?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.individual, container, false);

    <set various TextViews and ImageViews>

    MapboxAccountManager.start(getActivity(), MAPBOX_TOKEN);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView); // create map
    mapView.setStyleUrl(Style.LIGHT); // set MapBox streets style

    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

            <set various things on mapboxMap>
        }
    });

    mapView.setClickable(true);

    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.exceptions.InvalidAccessTokenException: 

    return view;
}
```

individual.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/individual_gridlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false">

    <!-- column 0 -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/divison_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="4"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@null"/>

    <!-- some TextViews here -->

    <!-- column 4 -->

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="4"
        mapbox:style_url="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
        mapbox:center_latitude="30.1"
        mapbox:center_longitude="-83.5"
        mapbox:zoom="11"/>

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inflating the view before calling `MapboxAccountManager`. It either needs to go before anything Mapbox related is done in code (including in XML) or a better option would be to [add it to your application object](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDKTestApp/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/testapp/MapboxApplication.java#L34) like done in our testapp.

Comment: Ah, *before the inflate*, didn't think of that.